# dirname(__FILE__) adds path after my domain

Tags: php, apache, path, absolute, dirname

Here's my problem using the PHP function dirname()

Let me first explain, I'm working on a website where I defined a constant as follow :

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

That worked well on a shared hosting, but I had to move the website on a dedicated server and now some files I try to call with an absolute link return 404. When I look what path they use, something like this appears :

```
http://myIp/var/www/myWebsite/[...]/image.jpg
```

What happens is that, my 'ROOT' constant is '/var/www/myWebsite' but in place of 'Replacing' my domain, it's added at the end of it. Which makes no sense since my Apache VirtualHost sends all requests towards 'myIp' to the local folder '/var/www/myWebsite'.

I don't know if the mistake is either from my PHP code, or my Apache VirtualHost.

Thank you for your help, I'm sure it's something stupid but I can't figure what I did wrong :)

Comment: Why don't you define that `ROOT` constant concretely? Deducing the relative website path segment from the current working dir is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: Yeah I would like to, what I need is just a constant variable that I can call to shorten the calls for images, I though that was the correct way to do it, but since dirname() is turning a relative path to an absolute path, I'm probably not doing the cleanest thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing server paths with site paths.

You would not want to use dirname to give you a path for a web asset.

What you could do if you really want to do it this way is to remove the path to your web root.

This might work:

`define('ROOT', str_replace('/var/www/myWebsite/', '/', dirname(__FILE__)));`

Comment: You're right and it approach from what I want, but then, how do you call the root site path ? I though root site path and root server path were identic

Comment: The root web site path is / whereas the absolute path on the server to the web root is /var/www/myWebsite/ (or whatever it is )